# Angular Google Maps component Icon is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I use [Angular Google Maps component](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/README.md) and all are working fine except the custom Icon. I have set it like below. Can you tell me why it is not working?

```
 mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: store.latitude, lng: store.longitude },
            zoom: 11,
            mapId: environment.googleMapId,
            icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
            

        } as google.maps.MapOptions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I need to set it under `MarkerOptions` like so:

```
markerOptions: {
                icon: {
                    url:
                        'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
                   

                }, draggable: false
            }
```